# Creating aliases for version specific macports ports

Tags: mac, python, package-management, macports

In Macports, I've just installed 'python27' along with various 'py27-*' ports.

I've noticed that ports like 'py27-nose' and 'py27-pip' are available in my path as 'nose-2.7' and 'pip-2.7'.  I can use 'python_select' to choose my default version of python but does macports have sort some of alternatives system for other binaries or do I need to manually create my own aliases?

Answer (score 1):

There is a an incomplete way of switching between versions binaries it is the port python_select but only does the binaries in the base puthon install.

e.g. it symlinks /opt/local/bin/python to the python2.x version

It could do this for nose etc if a line for nose was added into base and python27 (and others) in /opt/local/etc/select/python

Answer (score 0):

You'll have to create your own shell aliases. You could also make a symlink from `/opt/local/bin/nose` to `/opt/local/bin/nose-2.7`.